# Mass Entry in Java?

Tags: java, excel

I took one class in Java last semester and have forgotten almost everything. What I'm trying to do is make e-mails for new students by combining

```
first name + last name + @college.edu.
```

I have an excel spreadsheet with 5,000+ names, and doing it one by one will kill me and take forever. Is there anyway I can write a program that will take the information I copy from my excel spreadsheet and output it in email form?

Example:

```
CELL1 CELL2
John   Smith
Patty  Smith
Roger  Ebert
George Costanza
```

Output:

```
John.smith@college.edu
Patty.smith@college.edu
Roger.ebert@college.edu
George.costanza@college.edu
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Chase

Comment: As long as you find out 3 things, you'll find this very easy. --- 1. Reading a spreadsheet. --- 2. Creating an email string from the data. --- 3. Outputting it.

Comment: A simple excel formula will do it for you, and then you can drag it 5000 places down, then copy the result. No need for much programming...

Answer (score 5):

You could ofcourse do it in Java. However, I would suggest using an `Excel` formula to do this (it's easier and quicker), e.g.:

```
=CONCATENATE(CELL1, ".", CELL2, "@college.edu")
```

And drag it to other cells to fill their values.

Answer (score 1):

Darshan's answer is probably the most efficient way to get what you need done. OR you could write a function that uses `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` to parse the CSV data.

Check this out: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/